# Get name from within a function defined with var

Tags: javascript, function

I need, from within a function, to get it's name (actually I'm going up the stack a bit with .caller but that shouldn't change the problem).

'arguments.callee.name' would solve my problem IF my function had been named. But my functions are declared with **var myFunc = function() {}**, and changing that is not a possibility (I'm using CoffeeScript which always compiles to var declarations).

So how could I get to the variable to which the function was assigned?

**This is for debugging purposes so I'm not worried about performance, I'll use whatever operations get me to the name no matter the processing/time cost.**

**EDIT:** For the record, this is what I implemented in CoffeeScript based on the chosen answer's recommended library:

```
window.log = (msg) ->
  caller = printStackTrace()[4]
  caller = caller.substring 0, caller.indexOf('(') - 1
  if typeof msg is 'object'
    console.log "v --- at #{ caller }: ---"
    console.log msg
  else console.log "> --- at #{ caller }: " + msg
```

Works like a charm, thanks everyone!

Comment: Short of doing an analysis of the code just before the point of invocation I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Well, such functions don't have a name, that's why they're called 'anonymous functions'.

Comment: modern browser JS debuggers do this (compare a stacktrace with anonymous functions in Chrome to say IE7), but they have a lot more context to go off of.

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this in the first place? If it is for debugging then the debuggers in most recent browsers are more convenient and powerful.

Comment: It is for debugging, and because of CoffeeScript. I'm pretty limited on debugging so I want to auto-include the caller's name whenever I log stuff to console.

Comment: if i'm not wrong you can use **this** as handle to the function

Comment: @PeterRowell do you mean I should get to my function caller's code and try to find it's invocation? What if it's not the only thing on the line? Is there an algorithm to this analysis?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani sorry to say that you're wrong on that :-)

Comment: @VicSzpilman you cannot reliably get a name for an anonymous function, as it can have any number of names, while actually having no name at all. That's why declaring functions that way is kind-of a bad idea when a plain function definition statement would work  equally well. If Coffeescript translates that way, well, I would consider that to be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [this javascript stacktrace project on github](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace).  In particular, note the findFunctionName method in [stacktrace.js](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace/blob/master/stacktrace.js).

Basically they re-fetch the javascript source using XMLHTTPRequest and pull the line where the function was declared.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having trouble seeing how to use it outside of error-producing situations, though. How can I simply use such a method as findFunctionName from within a function I define (e.g. a logging function)?

Comment: You can produce an error (and of course catch it immediately).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Google Chrome, you can use the Stack Tracing API to get at that information.  See: http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi

Comment: But how could I use this mentioned CallSite API directly to get a context-inferred function name from within that function itself? quoted: "The structured stack trace is an Array of CallSite objects, each of which represents a stack frame. A CallSite object defines the following methods:(..)"